# Filtering a table in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a database attached to a C# project, with 3 tables Company, Product, and Inventory.  Inventory lists CompanyID, ProductID, and Quantity.  Combobox1 lists all the companyID.  When you select one, I want listview1 to display only the rows in Inventory with that CompanyID.

```
//binding DB to memorycopy   
this.DBContext = new DBEntities();

listView1.ItemsSource = this.SupPartContext.SPs;
GridViewColumn companyIDColumn = new GridViewColumn();
sNumColumn.Width = 90;
sNumColumn.Header = "companyID";
sNumColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("COMPANYID");

GridViewColumn ProductIDColumn = new GridViewColumn();
pNumColumn.Width = 90;
pNumColumn.Header = "ProductID";
pNumColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("PRODUCTID");
GridViewColumn quantityColumn = new GridViewColumn();
qtyColumn.Width = 90;
qtyColumn.Header = "quantity";
qtyColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("QUANTITY");
GridView newGridview = new GridView();
newGridview.Columns.Add(companyIDColumn);
newGridview.Columns.Add(productIDColumn);
newGridview.Columns.Add(quantityColumn);

listView1.View = newGridview;
```

Any help, even a point in the right direction would be appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting the list view to change automatically without writing any code you're probably not going to be able to get that to happen. However, if you rebind the list when the combo box value changes with the following line it will filter the list as you expect.

```
listView1.ItemsSource = this.SupPartContext.SPs.Where(sp => sp.CompanyID = {get the select company from the row here})
```

Comment: When I do that, I get several errors, including "Delegate 'System.Func<ProdCom.SP, int, bool> does not take 1 arguments"  Here is the full line of code  listView1.ItemsSource = this.SupPartContext.SPs.Where(sp => sp.CompanyID= comboBoxGetList.SelectedItem);  error starts after Where(